# Why would PHP included via a function return a different result from the PHP in the main file?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, for-loop, php-include

I'm trying to run a loop on WordPress that returns user information. When I have the PHP code to echo the results in the same file as the query, it works as expected. However, if I use `include` to access a transformation held elsewhere, it doesn't return any information, even if the code in the included file is identical. Why would this be?

My loop is below:

```
<?php

// The Query
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'include' => array( 1, 2, 3 ) ) );
// User Loop
if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
    foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
?>

<?php transform('user_directory'); echo $user->display_name; ?>

<?php
    }
} else {
    echo 'No users found.';
}
?>
```

`Transform` is a simple function that includes another page by name:

```
function transform($transformation) {
    include 'transformations/'.$transformation.'.php';
}
```

In this case, the `echo` command works, whereas the included file (via `Transform`) doesn't. The included file is definitely being found and is rendering other html and PHP code perfectly, it just doesn't seem able to find anything under `$user`.

The code held in the included PHP file is:

```
<?php echo $user->display_name; //Won't return this text
echo "It returns this text fine"; ?>
```

Am I not able to access an array created on one page with included code from another?

Comment: Not unless it's a global variable. Try to add a `global $user` above your lines that aren't working.

Comment: As rnevious said before, you are in the wrong context. I would advise you to set the error_reporting to E_ALL and turn error reporting on while developing, than you can see such errors easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, you are including it from a function.
A function, in PHP, does have it's own scope.
The included file will inherit the, empty, scope of the function.
You could pass the `$user` to the function:

```
function transform($transformation, $user) {
    include 'transformations/'.$transformation.'.php';
}

...

<?php transform('user_directory', $user); echo $user->display_name; ?>
```

This will set the `$user` variable, and make it accessible by the included file.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: That's it, thanks! First time programming PHP in about ten years, so I'm a little rusty.